# How Can I Write An Integration Test For A Gradle Plugin

Tags: gradle

I'm writing [a plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/alexec/docker-gradle-plugin). It's a port of a Maven plugin, which I testing using the Maven integration testing plugin. I'd like to create a series of tests for different `build.gradle` files.

Is there a good way to do this is Gradle (as what I have does not seem to work).

Comment: What you need is tooling API: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/embedding.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way to make a simple test is use the org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder class.

```
Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
project.apply plugin: 'dependencyAnalysis'
project.apply plugin: 'java'

assertTrue(project.tasks.analyze instanceof AnalyzeTask)
```

This can however only test up to and including the configuration phase. So for a test of the execution phase this will not work.

You can also use the tooling API like Opal suggested, but I would suggest that you use it through the nebula test plugin. https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-test

Answer (score 1):

The [Gradle TestKit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html) has recently been added to the Gradle distribution to help with integration testing. At the time of writing it has some missing features but I have used it and it is very useful. I have not used nebula-test so cannot compare them.